# Dante server cannot use ip public as socks

Tags: yaml, dante

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCQhG.png)hello I'm trying to use the dante server as a socks5 proxy on my vps but when it finishes and checks "/etc/init.d/sockd status" it says the local ip of my vps my question is how can my public ip be connected or used on a dante server

iam already try to add public ip on 00-installer-config.yaml but it doesn't work